# Getting data from JSON array in PHP foreach statement

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am trying to get data from a JSON array - the array is very complex in structure.

This is my array:

```
Array
(
[query] => Plagiarism is the "wrongful appropriation" and "stealing and publication"
[data] => Array
    (
        [error] => 0
        [webs] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [title] => Plagiarism - Wikipedia
                        [url] => https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism
                        [des] => 
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [title] => Plagiarism - Wikipedia
                        [url] => https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism
                        [des] => Plagiarism is the "wrongful appropriation" and "stealing and publication" of another author's "language, thoughts, ideas, or expressions" and the representation of them as one's own original work. Plagiarism is considered academic dishonesty and a breach of journalistic ethics.
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [title] => What is the concept of plagiarism? - ResearchGate
                        [url] => https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_concept_of_plagiarism
                        [des] => “Plagiarism is the "wrongful appropriation" and "stealing and publication" of another author's "language, thoughts, ideas, or expressions" and the representation of them as one's own original work.
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [title] => essay1 | Plagiarism | Crime & Justice - Scribd
                        [url] => https://www.scribd.com/document/252964635/essay1
                        [des] => Plagiarism is the "wrongful appropriation" and "stealing and publication" of another author's"language, thoughts, ide...
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [title] => ARSSS
                        [url] => http://www.arsss.org/plagiarism.php
                        [des] => Plagiarism is the "wrongful appropriation" and "stealing and publication" of another author's "language, thoughts, ideas, or expressions" and the representation of them as one's own original work. Plagiarism is considered academic dishonesty and a breach of journalistic ethics.
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [title] => Plagiarism - Plagiarism - wattpad.com
                        [url] => https://www.wattpad.com/199706948-plagiarism
                        [des] => Plagiarism is the "wrongful appropriation" and "stealing and publication" of another author's "language, thoughts, ideas, or expressions" and the representation of them as one's own original work. The idea remains problematic …
                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [title] => A DEFINITION OF PLAGIARISM - cmplt.ovh WordPress
                        [url] => https://www.compilatio.net/en/plagiarism-definition/
                        [des] => a definition of plagiarism “Plagiarism is the “wrongful appropriation” and “stealing and publication” of another author‘s “language, thoughts, ideas, or expressions,” and the representation of them as one’s own original work.
                    )

                [7] => Array
                    (
                        [title] => What is plagiarism? | Yahoo Answers
                        [url] => https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20160301142448AALJsfV
                        [des] => Mar 01, 2016 · Plagiarism is the "wrongful appropriation" and "stealing and publication" of another author's "language, thoughts, ideas, or expressions" and the representation of them as one's own original work.[1][2] The idea remains problematic with unclear definitions and unclear rules.[3][4][5] The modern concept of plagiarism as immoral …
                    )

                [8] => Array
                    (
                        [title] => Reading: Plagiarism | ITE 115 Introduction to Computer ...
                        [url] => https://courses.lumenlearning.com/vccs-ite115-17sp/chapter/reading-plagiarism/
                        [des] => Introduction. Plagiarism is the “wrongful appropriation” and “stealing and publication” of another author’s “language, thoughts, ideas, or expressions” and the representation of them as one’s own original work.
                    )

                [9] => Array
                    (
                        [title] => Adis-Group - DEFENITION OF PLAGIARISM Plagiarism is the ...
                        [url] => https://www.coursehero.com/file/15841247/Adis-Group/
                        [des] => View Adis-Group from COMMERCE 1101 at University of Santo Tomas. DEFENITION OF PLAGIARISM Plagiarism is the "wrongful appropriation" and "stealing and publication" of another author's "language,
                    )

                [10] => Array
                    (
                        [title] => PLAGIARISM - Substantial Paper Guide - LibGuides at ...
                        [url] => http://libguides.library.arizona.edu/c.php?g=608443&p=4386531
                        [des] => There are many different definitions of plagiarism. Wikipedia defines it "as the wrongful appropriation and stealing and publication of another author's language, thoughts, ideas, or expressions and the representation of them as one's own original work."
                    )

            )

        [unique] => false
    )
```

)

I am trying to get the title key results. Here is my query:

```
$data = $someArray["data"];
foreach ($data as $result) {
    foreach ($result as $finalres) {
        echo $finalres["title"]."<br/>";
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the result I get. The list is diaplaying but a PHP error is shown above and below.

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\naris.com.ng\check_plagia.php on line 69
 1. Plagiarism - Wikipedia
2. Plagiarism - Wikipedia
3. What is the concept of plagiarism? - ResearchGate essay1 | Plagiarism |Crime & Justice - Scribd ARSSS
4. Plagiarism - Plagiarism - wattpad.com
5. A DEFINITION OF PLAGIARISM - cmplt.ovh WordPress
6. What is plagiarism? | Yahoo Answers
7. Reading: Plagiarism | ITE 115 Introduction to Computer ...
8. Adis-Group - DEFENITION OF PLAGIARISM Plagiarism is the ...
9. PLAGIARISM - Substantial Paper Guide - LibGuides at ...

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\naris.com.ng\check_plagia.php on line 69
```

I don't why the warning keeps showing even when the results displays?
How to I properly show the list without the PHP error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try with this code :**

Working demo : https://eval.in/1017825

```
$data = $someArray["data"]['webs'];

foreach ($data as $finalres) 
{
    echo $finalres["title"].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try use the key in foreach like

`foreach ($data as $key => $result) {}`

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0):

To output just the results you just need to pick the 'webs' elements...

```
foreach ($data['webs'] as $result) {
```

The errors your getting is that the first time round it's trying to use...

```
[query] => Plagiarism is the "wrongful appropriation" and "stealing and publication"
```

and iterate over this.